# JSON format Error

Tags: android

I want to pass address and want lat and long . But I got complete String from maps.google.com. But there is error in JSON format.

I try below Code

```
Error :Couldn't get connection factory client
```

getLocationInfo("3 cité Nollez Paris France");

```
public static void getLocationInfo(String address) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try {

        address = address.replaceAll(" ","%20");    

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address + "&sensor=false");
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();


            response = client.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
            int b;
            while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                stringBuilder.append((char) b);
            }

            System.out.print(stringBuilder);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {

            jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());

            longitute = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
                    .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                    .getDouble("lng");

                System.out.print(longitute);


                latitude = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
                    .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                    .getDouble("lat");

                System.out.print(latitude);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

      //  return jsonObject;
    }
```

LOGCAT

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
                "long_name" : "3",
                "short_name" : "3",
                "types" : [ "street_number" ]
             },
             {
                "long_name" : "CitÃ© Nollez",
                "short_name" : "CitÃ© Nollez",
                "types" : [ "route" ]
             },
             {
                "long_name" : "18th arrondissement of Paris",
                "short_name" : "18th arrondissement of Paris",
                "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
             },
             {
                "long_name" : "Paris",
                "short_name" : "Paris",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
             },
             {
              "long_name" : "Paris",
                "short_name" : "75",
                "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
             },
             {
                "long_name" : "Ã?le-de-France",
                "short_name" : "IdF",
                "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
             },
             {
                "long_name" : "France",
                "short_name" : "FR",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
             {
             "long_name" : "75018",
              "short_name" : "75018",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "3 CitÃ© Nollez, 75018 Paris, France",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 48.89376110,
               "lng" : 2.33742180
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 48.89511008029150,
                  "lng" : 2.338770780291502
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 48.89241211970850,
                  "lng" : 2.336072819708498
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
03-14 13:51:35.776: I/MapActivity(1430): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
03-14 13:51:35.776: E/MapActivity(1430): Couldn't get connection factory client
```

Comment: have you added permission for internet `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Comment: Has you mentioned "But there is error in JSON format" could you please attached received JSON string.

Comment: @Naveen Internet permission are not give before then how come the said that "But I got complete String from maps.google.com. But there is error in JSON format."

Comment: See Error Log. permission is proper.

Comment: This error generally comes in google map integration, it is surely not related to the JSON string, are you testing on emulator?

Comment: @Naveen : Then What is this , is above code tested in mac ? Find solution instead of suggestion

Comment: This is not even an error, it is normal in google map integration. I have seen it many times. you can search for it. If you have any other problem then tell.

Comment: So your problem is you cannot get /parse latitude longitude from JSON to your string right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code in your Map activity before super.onCreate()

**ExampleActivity:-**

```
 public class ExampleActivity extends Activity {

    // url to make request
    private static String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+address.replace(" ", "%20")+"&sensor=true";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tvlat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvlat);
        tvlng = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvlng);

        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
             System.out.println("Location Latitude"
                + json.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0)
                        .getJSONObject("geometry")
                        .getJSONObject("location").getString("lat"));

               System.out.println("Location Longitude"
                + json.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0)
                        .getJSONObject("geometry")
                        .getJSONObject("location").getString("lng"));    
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**JSONPareser:-**

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();            

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Then run your app, it worked fine for me.

Comment: Right ans. But I want solutions in my question

Comment: IF your app runs perfectly also you'll get that two messages First one is information and next one is error message.Can you say where you are facing problem exactly?

Comment: +1 but not accepted this ans because I want ans in my question

Comment: where you are facing problem?

Comment: Check my question , I write complete detail

Comment: The JSON format is also valid format,you can check with jsonLint.

Comment: Edited answer and printed Latitude and longitude of Geometries Location.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled these permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to worry if that "couldn't get connection error" while using maps.. it will work fine even after the occurrence of that.. If your code doesnt work then there is other reason. check to it..